# When is the speed specified for an object experiencing an exponential force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, integration

So this is the question given in my text book:

> *A particle of mass m is at rest at the origin at time $t = 0$. It is subjected to a force $F (t) = F_0e^{–bt}$ in the $x$
>   direction. Its speed $v(t)$ is depicted by which of the following curves? (I am not posting the curve.)*

And this is the solution in my textbook :-$$F= F_0e^{-bt}$$$$\implies a = \frac{F}{M}=\frac{F_0}{M}e^{-bt}$$$$\implies \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_0}{M}e^{-bt}$$$$\int dv=\int _0^t\frac{F_0}{M}e^{-bt}$$$$V=\frac{F}{Mb}e^{-bt}$$

So if I am right according to this at $t=0$ ,$V$ should be equal to $\frac{F}{Mb}$ but in my text book it is given at $t=\infty$ that $V=\frac{F}{Mb}$. So where am I making mistake can anyone point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the book forgot a term in the integral

$$\int_0^t \frac{F_0}{M} e^{-b t'}dt' = -\frac{F_0}{Mb} \left. \left( e^{-bt'}\right)\right|_0^t = \frac{F_0}{Mb}\left( 1 - e^{-bt} \right) $$

For $t\rightarrow \infty$ this goes to $F_0/bM$ and for $t=0$ it goes to $0$.

Comment: No i didn't forget it's the mistake in text book, i thought so something is wrong with the the integration i was just doing it again, thanks for the help

Comment: Edited to indicate that mistake was the book's and not yours. Apologies for the error.